# Jquery code showing up on partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a partial, `_user_review.html.erb`, and I just created a `_user_review.js.erb` to match it. This is so the following JQuery listener gets loaded when the view loads:

```
$(function(){
    $("#review_rating").on('change', function(){
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Now when the partial loads, all I see is this code instead of my view.
I'm sure this is a noob mistake but when it comes to JQuery that's my specialty.

Comment: Thanks for making my post readable!

Comment: How are you including the javascript partial?

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem, just rename `_user_review_js.erb` to `user_review.js.erb`

and render like `<%= render "my_controller/user_review" %>`

If you just want to load the JavaScript, you can just place the code in the `html.erb`

in `my_controller/_user_review.html.erb`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      $("#review_rating").on('change', function(){
          this.form.submit();
      });
  });
</script>
<!-- partial view here-->
```

then just render it

```
<%= render "my_controller/user_review" %>
```

Comment: Hi D3mon, thanks for this. There was a typo on the .js, but in fact it was properly formatted. Question: doesn't your solution go against unobtrusive Javascript?

Comment: It was not clear how you were using the js.erb.  Are you doing any ajax?  I did not see that.  I would update the question with more details showing the steps taking place in order.